35mm roll came out weird
I just bought an olympus AF-10 super and it’s giving me some problems. First of all, every time I put in a new battery the next day it’s already flat and I need to change it; to kinda “”solve”” this I usually put the battery inside just moments before taking a picture and after the roll automatically rewinds I take it out. Now I just finished the first roll with this camera (24 shots) and after it got developed I noticed something weird: the first ten shots came out perfectly, while the remaining are all like the ones that you can see in the photos. Does anyone know why did this happen? Could it be related to the battery problem?  



It looks like the back of the camera was opened while the film was wound around the take-up spool in the camera. You can see the shadow of the tensioner attached to the pressure plate that is spring loaded and presses against the back of the film as it winds onto the take-up spool.

The reason the first few frames were fine is that they were wound tightly enough onto the take-up spool and the remaining layers of film wound outside of them protected them from the light when the camera back was opened.
This has nothing to do with the battery. It has to do with the fact that undeveloped film is always sensitive to light, and exposing it to any amount of light by opening the back of the camera when the film is not wound into the film's cartridge will fog the film.
One thing you might try regarding battery life is to be sure and close the lens cover completely when not using the camera. It's unclear from the Olympus AF-10 Super Instructions, but many such compact cameras will stay powered on when the cover is opened and only power down when it is closed.
